# Extracted files from PDF - Need to recompile

Tags: pdf

so short story, i needed to extract a PDF file from my bluestacks VM, unfortunately due to the app's nature i was using it did not come in PDF format, instead it was a folder which i zipped and uploaded and downloaded on my PC. Here's what i looks like: https://gyazo.com/4c83dc59e6f133a653d35b20d906bd4d

Is there away for me to recompile it back into a PDF? thanks.

Comment: You are better off saving in the correct format to start with: see for example [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/235134/how-to-print-to-pdf-on-any-computer-smartphone-or-tablet/).

Comment: @AFH I've tried converting zip into pdf, that didn't work. And save what in the correct format, they're all text format files

Comment: A PDF is an electronic image of a printed document: how do you imagine that the files in the ZIP would be printed? If they can be printed in the VM, then save the print as a PDF instead; if they can't be printed in the VM, then it makes no sense to try to produce a PDF from them.

Comment: @AFH  I know...The point is i have no PDF files, i have the inside of an PDF file, all of the fonts files, styling files, png pictures of book, etc, i need to reformat it all into a PDF.

Comment: How were these components extracted, and where is the original PDF source?

Comment: @AFH They were extracted by a cloud app, i'm not sure how they were extracted, guessing decompiled

Comment: The original PDF must be somewhere.

Comment: @AFH not that i can find, there's a bunch of corrupt PNG files though.

Comment: With the minimum amount of information you have given, it is impossible to take this further. I have no idea what applications you are using or how you are using them. You will need to expand your question with this level of detail before we can take it further.